# Convert 3 ways to 4 way Wiring

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, multiway-switch

I am hoping someone can help me.  I have a 3 way switch for lights on my stairs and a 3 way switch for lights in the hallway.  The way they are currently wired is there is a 2 gang box at bottom of the stairs, power into that box. There are currently 2 3 way switches in that box, one for the stairs, one for the hall.  The at each end, the box then runs to the lights.  My question; is there any way to put a 4 way switch in the 2 gang box and run all the lights on the same switch, so they all come on and off together?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in all boxes involved?

Answer (score 2):

#### Smart Switches to the Rescue

You *might* be able to use the existing wiring for 4-way switches. But a simpler solution, and one that does **not** require any new wiring (just reconfiguration of the existing wires and new switches) is **smart switches**.

There are many brands and many different types. You will need to do your research carefully as there are different requirements for neutral & ground and possibly other things. But basically, you should be able to:

- Install a "master" switch where power comes in from the breaker panel (likely the 2-gang box, but not 100% certain without more details)
- Install "remotes" at the other 2 locations. Depending on the brand/type, the remotes may use AC power themselves or they may be battery powered (with long-lasting batteries).
- In addition to controlling the lights with the 3 switches, you can also have (if you want) options to control via WiFi or other means.

Make sure to get UL-listed (or similar *listing*, CE and FCC are not equivalent to UL) devices. Since at a minimum the master switch will be attached directly to 120V (or 240V, depending on your location) power, safety is very important.

Comment: Given the use of american terminology it's almost certainly 120V

Answer (score 0):

you don't have enough conductors in the walls to put in a 4 way switch, because the string of switches needs two travellers between each and its neighbours, and live to one end and the load at the other end.

Comment: You *might* be right, but I think it is too early to tell without more information from OP.

Comment: there is a small probability that there are unused wires present, but the original description seems clear enough to me